# How to do a split in java?

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have done a string.split and then called the first position of the array but for some reason all of the array result appear. This is my code

```
try {
    String xx = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            Cell z = s.getCell(c, i);

            xx = xx + z.getContents() + "\n";
        }

        xx = xx + "\n";

    }
    //I do the split here but the result[0] = all the information
    String result[] = xx.split(",");
    textView.setText(result[0]);
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

**And this is an image of the output:**
[Description of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYDol.png)

Comment: you aren't adding `,` between the `Strings`

Comment: So can you help me?

Comment: What is the format of the String returned by `z.getContents()` ? Give an example `String`.

Comment: text\text2....I put an image of the output

Comment: Why do you expect `.split(",")` to do anything if the string has no commas?

Comment: if each *text* is separated by `\ `, as you just mentioned, there is no use splitting with `,`. Use `\ `, *i.e.*, the character which actually does separate the `Strings`

Comment: so what do you recomend? Im new at java sorry :S

Comment: Can you put an example below?

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you understand what the `split()` function does? Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: yes but where do I put the "\" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting with `\\\\`. Like

```
String exampleString = "A\\B\\C\\D"; //escaping the "\" character
String array[] = exampleString.split("\\\\");
```